# SQL- How to add a column to the SQL VIEW, but not add or update it to the table?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

How to add column to the SQL THAT LIST USA as "America" India as "Asia" China as "Asia" and so on without actually adding the data to the tables but only include in the view. I want to include both COUNTRY_VISITED and new column named CONTINENTS.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_HOLIDAYS 
AS
    SELECT CODE_OF_HOLIDAY, DESCRIPTION, COUNTRY_VISITED
    FROM ZZZ_HOLIDAY_DETAILS;
```

Comment: WHat table is USA, India and China from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_HOLIDAYS AS
SELECT  CODE_OF_HOLIDAY, 
        DESCRIPTION, 
        case when COUNTRY_VISITED = 'USA' then 'America'
             when COUNTRY_VISITED in ('India','China') then 'Asia'
             else COUNTRY_VISITED 
        end as COUNTRY_VISITED 
FROM ZZZ_HOLIDAY_DETAILS;
```

Comment: OK, this is good, but I still want to keep the COUNTRY_VISITED column but include the extra column lets say called CONTINENT which  is not in the table and I don't want to include it in there but just in VIEW. Can you help.

Comment: OK I figured it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_HOLIDAYS 
AS
    SELECT CODE_OF_HOLIDAY, DESCRIPTION, COUNTRY_VISITED,
           (CASE WHEN COUNTRY_VISITED = 'USA' THEN 'AMERICA'
                 WHEN COUNTRY_VISITED IN ('INDIA', 'CHINA') THEN 'ASIA'
            END) as CONTINENT
    FROM ZZZ_HOLIDAY_DETAILS;
```

Comment: OK, this is good, but I still want to keep the COUNTRY_VISITED column but include the extra column lets say called CONTINENT which is not in the table and I don't want to include it in there but just in VIEW. Can you help.

Comment: OK I figured it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT CODE_OF_HOLIDAY, DESCRIPTION, COUNTRY_VISITED, 
 CASE WHEN COUNTRY_VISITED = 'USA' THEN 'America' 
      WHEN COUNTRY_VISITED = 'China' THEN 'Asia' 
      WHEN COUNTRY_VISITED = 'India' THEN 'Asia' ELSE COUNTRY_VISITED 
 END AS COUNTRY_VISITED_ALIAS
 FROM ZZZ_HOLIDAY_DETAILS
```

Comment: OK, this is good, but I still want to keep the COUNTRY_VISITED column but include the extra column lets say called CONTINENT which is not in the table and I don't want to include it in there but just in VIEW. Can you help.

Comment: OK I figured it out. Thank you